# attach to docker image in IntelliJ

Tags: docker, debugging, intellij-idea

I am trying to setup IntelliJ to debug a Springboot app running in a docker container.
I configured a docker image (by specifying an image id) and created a remote app configuration which has "launch docker container" pre-action or whatever these are called.
When I start debug for that remote configuration it launches the docker container successfully but then fails to connect to port 5005 to start debugging.
I am confused, how is this even supposed to work?  Do I need to specify something in the docker container config to expose port 5005?
More specifically I get:

```
error running 'Unnamed Remote Debug': Unable to open debugger port (localhost:5005): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To make your application "debuggable" you would need to launch it with `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=0.0.0.0:5005` option enabled so that the java process exposes a debbuger inside the container process (I assume that the main process in your container is `java` process)
2. When IntelliJ is run on host system and your app in the container, you need to publish the port to the host system so that IntelliJ can reach the debugger.

In your case I managed to create configuration that launches image with custom entrypoint and exposes a debugger inside the container :

1. Create a Docker configuration for your image :
   [image]
   The command needs to be :

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=0.0.0.0:5005 -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar app.jar
```

so a debugger will be created on port `5005` alongside with main java process. Also remember to change your jar name at the end of this command.

2. Create a Remote configuration that depends on your Docker image configuration :
   [image]
   The "Before launch step" needs to be added so that your container is launched before starting to debug:
   [image]
   And then just launch your remote configuration and it should work. Launching it will start a container with your app with enabled debugger and debugger port exposed. The port `8080` is port where your app runs :

```
$ docker container ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
c7f5f2e3a7b7        21225d2e368e        "java -agentlib:jdwp…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:5005->5005/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   myapp
```

Comment: Thank you.  In my defense I realized that i need to stuff that command into the docker after posting the question.  The write up is beautiful.  I will accept once I confirm it attaches.

Comment: Well, so since I am using spring-boot:build-image I couldn't just do it the way you suggested -- command is not java, it uses some crazy paketo CNB (?) layers and a customer launcher app.  So I made it work by setting env variable: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=5005,server=y,suspend=n

Comment: Also worth noting that doing the debug "start docker before launch" thing also didn't work.  It failed to start docker image with some strange error about ports not being available.  But if I manually start docker and then start the debug it works.  Well, actually it kind of doesn't -- IntelliJ fails to open the right source file.  But it definitely hits a breakpoint.